# Workflow or 'Shading Mode' for Aligning gameObject in a Scene?

Tags: unity, level-design

I'm aligning and placing gameObjects in a Unity scene. I have difficulty seeing the vertices and objects because the scene supposed to be dark (my workaround is to increase ambient lighting temporarily).

**Is there any workflow or 'Shading Mode' that artists use specifically for placing and aligning gameObjects in a scene?**

Comment: Have you tried turning off lighting in the scene view?

Comment: @DMGregory: No. What method to do so? Should I go to Lighting Explorer and turn them off one by one or is there another option to turn off lighting at once? But why should I turn off lighting in the first place? It's counter-intuitive.

Comment: You read the [documentation about the scene view controls including the section "2D, Lighting, and Audio Switches"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ViewModes.html) right?

Comment: @DMGregory: oh, I see what you meant. From "turning off lighting in the scene view", you meant that lighting toggle i.e. the sun icon on the scene view which toggle between ambient lighting and your custom in-game lighting. That actually would be my answer I guess because a developer does not need necessarily to change in-game parameters to be able to align gameObjects.